# Display a table beside a plot in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new at using PyQt and this is my first GUI application. I have a challenge trying to display a table beside a plot in iterations. Please find below my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib qt5
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 780, 533))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.scene.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.vis_plot)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 25))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


    def vis_plot(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns = list('ABCD'))
        ax1 = self.figure.add_subplot(1,2,1)
        ax2 = self.figure.add_subplot(1,2,2)
        for column in df:
            col = pd.DataFrame(df[column])
            col.plot.hist(ax=ax1, title=str(column))
            col_stat = col.apply([np.min, np.max, np.mean, np.median])
            col_table = col_stat.rename(index={'amin':'Minimum', 'amax':'Maximum','mean':'Mean', 'median':'Median'})
            col_table.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
            col_tablerender = col_table.rename(columns={col_table.columns[0]:'Metric', col_table.columns[1]:'Value'})
            ax2.table(cellText = col_tablerender.values,
                     colWidths=[0.25]*len(df[column]),
                     colLabels=col_tablerender.columns,
                     cellLoc='center',
                     loc='left',
                     bbox=[-1,0.7,.6,.3])
            self.canvas.draw()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is what I am currently getting:

What I currently have

[image]

I would prefer if the table is not plotted but printed beside the corresponding plots like the image below:

What I want

[image]

Comment: Just use any layout to arrange the widgets as you want. E.g. `HBoxLayout` (for the rows) in combination with `VBoxLayout` (for the columns). Or `GridLayout` as you have it already in your example. You just need to add the widgets at the desired positions.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know the widget to use to print / display the table. In addition, I do not want to display the table as a dataframe. I would prefer something simple like in the attached image. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you have preformatted text then you can use [`QTextEdit`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html) otherwise you can create the table manually via [`QTableWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html). For more complex tables you can also split the table into [model](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemmodel.html) and [view](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html).

Comment: @a_guest Thank you. As suggested, I created a qtextdocument in a qtextedit widget and I inserted a texttable and qimage with qtextcursor, but my challenge now is I can't get the table and image to display side by side. I tried changing the cursor position to the right before inserting the image, but this moved the image to the right below the text table. I will appreciate any form of help or suggestion on how to get this done. Thank you again.

Comment: Just create a `QGridLayout` and put the single elements in place. From your description it sounds like you want two columns, one row and have the table in the left column and the plot in the right one.

Comment: @a_guest Thank you for your prompt response. The qtextEdit widget is already in a gridlayout. And yes, that is exactly what I want. Hod do I combine the table and the image as a single element?