# Align qtexttable and qimage side by side in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am currently building a GUI using pyqt, does anyone know how I can align a qtexttable and a qimage next to each other in a qtextdocument. They are presently stacked but I would prefer if they can be inserted side by side. Please find below my code. The table and image are both embedded in the qtextdocument.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib qt5
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 780, 533))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setAcceptRichText(True)
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        self.textEdit.setDocument(document)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)


        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.vis_plot)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 25))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


    def vis_plot(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns = list('ABCD'))
        ax1 = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        for column in df:
            col = pd.DataFrame(df[column])
            col_stat = col.apply([np.min, np.max, np.mean, np.median])
            col_table = col_stat.rename(index={'amin':'Minimum', 'amax':'Maximum','mean':'Mean', 'median':'Median'})
            col_table.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
            col_tablerender = col_table.rename(columns={col_table.columns[0]:'Metric', col_table.columns[1]:'Value'})
            cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
            cursor.insertTable(len(col_tablerender), 2)
            for id, value in col_tablerender.iterrows():
                for row in value:
                    cursor.insertText(str(row))
                    cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)

            col.plot.hist(ax=ax1, title=str(column))
            self.canvas.draw()
            size = self.canvas.size()
            width, height = size.width(), size.height()
            im = QtGui.QImage(self.canvas.buffer_rgba(), width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
            cursor.insertImage(im)       


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would prefer something that looks like this

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks!

Comment: @ZackTarr Thank you for your response. I have added the code to my question.

Comment: @ZackTarr, still waiting for your help.

Comment: @S.Nick could you please help take a look at my question. I will appreciate any form of help from you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a table beside a plot in PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235632/display-a-table-beside-a-plot-in-pyqt5)